# PHP - Syntax Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a syntax error in my php code and just cannot figure out how should I fix it. I've been trying for ages and narrowed down the faulty code to the following :

```
<?php 
global $post;
$tax_classes = array_filter( array_map( 'trim', explode( "\n", get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_classes' ) ) ) );

if ( ! class_exists( 'Tax_Meta_Boxes' ) ) :

class Tax_Meta_Boxes {

    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'tax_meta_data' ) );
    }
}
?>
```

I ran the code through the PHP checker, the error seems to be with the last line and `?>`.
I tried fiddling around with it, remove it, but error still there.

The error is caused by the function :

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Tax_Meta_Boxes' ) ) :

class Tax_Meta_Boxes {

    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'tax_meta_data' ) );
    }
}
```

If I remove the function, my error is gone, but what is wrong in the code of this function, how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed `endif;` for your `if()`

```
<?php 
global $post;
$tax_classes = array_filter( array_map( 'trim', explode( "\n", get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_classes' ) ) ) );

if ( ! class_exists( 'Tax_Meta_Boxes' ) ) :

class Tax_Meta_Boxes {

    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'tax_meta_data' ) );
    }
}

endif;// this line

?>
```